# Connection issue using SSH Private key

Tags: ssh, terraform

I am very new with terraform and trying to explore. I am using digitalocean as resource. I am able to create droplet and now want to provision it with some software. But unable to make connection with it.

I am using virtual machine over my laptop so want to use my private SSH key to access droplet. So i copy my SSH key in a file over terraform machine and giving its path. Below is my configuration:

```
provider "digitalocean" {
  token = "${var.do_token}"
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  name = "web"
  size = "${var.size}"
  image = "${var.image}"
  region = "${var.region}"
  ssh_keys = [23625200]
  private_networking = "true"
}
connection {
  user = "root"
  type = "ssh"
  private_key = "${file("/root/id_rsa")}"
  timeout = "2m"
 }
```

My laptop private key is available over terraform machine in `/root/id_rsa` file.

I am getting below error when trying to validate or plan:

```
Error: Unknown root level key: connection
```

Can you please help me whats wrong i am doing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do something automatically over SSH such as install some software when the droplet is created? Or do you just want access to it for ad-hoc later connections? If it's the former then you need to define this [connection as part of a provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html). If the latter you don't need it at all.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, Yes..once the SSH connection become successful i will install some software as well because we will do provisioing also via terraform.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I read some article and all are showing that we can define the connection inside ``resource`. I will define the connection inside `provisioner` but i have one more question we need to define connection every `provisioner` if we are using multiple provisioner inside single `.tf`file?

Answer (score 1):

Your [`connection` block should be part of a provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html), which in turn is part of a resource (potentially the [`null_resource` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) if no other resource makes sense).

So in your case you should have something like this:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  name               = "web"
  size               = "${var.size}"
  image              = "${var.image}"
  region             = "${var.region}"
  ssh_keys           = [23625200]
  private_networking = "true"

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host        = "${self.ipv4_address}"
      user        = "root"
      type        = "ssh"
      private_key = "${file("/root/id_rsa")}"
      timeout     = "2m"
    }

    inline = [
      "yum -y install httpd",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. Now i am able to SSH and install the software on my droplet.